# Checking that a sequence of independent random variables satisfies a specific condition.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume you have $X_i$ a sequence of independent random variables such that $X_i\leq M$ almost surely, and $\sum_i Var(X_i)=\infty$. Construct the array $$Y_{n,m}=\frac{X_m-E(X_m)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i)}}$$ I need to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^n E(Y_{n,m}^2;|Y_{n,m}|>\varepsilon)=0$$ for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it $X_i \le M$ or $|X_i| \le M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: Im assuming that you mean $|X_k|\le M$ a.s. and that $E[X; A]:=\int_A XdP$.*

WLOG you can assume that $E[X_m]=0$ for all $m$, then $Y^2_{n,m}=\frac{X^2_m}{b_n}$ for $b_n:=E[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2]=V[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k]\to\infty$, therefore
$$
\sum_{m=1}^nE[Y^2_{n,m}; A_{n,m}]\le M^2\frac1{b_n}\sum_{m=1}^n\int \mathbf 1_{A_{n,m}}dP=M^2\frac1{b_n}\sum_{m=1}^n\Pr[A_{n,m}]
$$
where $A_{n,m}:=\{Y^2_{n,m}>\epsilon ^2\}=\{X^2_m>\epsilon^2 b_n\}$. As the $X_m$ are bounded then we find that $\Pr[A_{n,m}\text{ i.o.}]=0$. This together with the independence of the $X_m$ and the second Borel-Cantelli lemma show us that $\sum_{m\ge 1}\Pr[A_{n,m}]<\infty$, therefore the result is clear.